# Fill null values with previous string from the same column using condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe with missing values on one column and I am trying to fill those missing values with the previous string from the same column but given that Another column == something.   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZM0D.jpg)

for instance I want to populate missing values under 'Name' with the previous string only for those rows where Business Unit='GTI Shared S2D'

let's say we have a dataframe like this

### Name Part Size(GB) Business Unit

579 srv005831   120.0  GTI Shared S2D
580 Nan         50.0    GTI Shared S2D
581 Nan         30.0    GTI Shared S2D
582 srv000711   120.0   GTI Shared S2D
583 Nan         50.0    GTI Shared S2D  
584 Nan         20      Call centre

the output should look like this

### Name Part Size(GB) Business Unit

```
579 srv005831   120.0   GTI Shared S2D  <br/>
580 srv005831   50.0    GTI Shared S2D   <br/> 
581 srv005831           30.0    GTI Shared S2D <br/> 
582 srv000711   120.0   GTI Shared S2D   <br/>
583 srv000711   50.0    GTI Shared S2D        <br/> 
584  Nan         20      Call centre     <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffill()`:

```
x[x['Business Unit'] == 'GTI Shared S2D']['Name'].ffill()
```

Take below df for example:

```
In [331]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['srv005831', 'srv005632', np.nan, np.nan], 'Part Size(GB)':[120.0, 50.0, 30.0, 120.0], 'Business Unit':['GTI Shared S2D', 'Call Center', 'GTI Shared S2D', 'GTI Shared S2D']})

In [332]: df
Out[332]: 
        Name  Part Size(GB)   Business Unit
0  srv005831          120.0  GTI Shared S2D
1  srv005632           50.0     Call Center
2        NaN           30.0  GTI Shared S2D
3        NaN          120.0  GTI Shared S2D
```

My code runs fine:

```
In [339]: ix = df[df['Business Unit'] == 'GTI Shared S2D'].index.tolist()

In [346]: df.loc[ix] = df.loc[ix]['Name'].ffill()

In [347]: df
Out[347]: 
        Name Part Size(GB) Business Unit
0  srv005831     srv005831     srv005831
1  srv005632            50   Call Center
2  srv005831     srv005831     srv005831
3  srv005831     srv005831     srv005831
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but all the othere values where Business unit is not equal to Nan are now Nan

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: @KhutsoMphelo Please refer to the the example I've added in my answer.

Comment: I have edited the question please check at for the expected output